# How To Lock A block of code for a Thread in Java

Tags: java, android, multithreading, jakarta-ee

consider the below code.

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {

    int limit;

    public MyThread(int limit, String name) {
        super();
        this.limit = limit;
        this.setName(name);
    }

    public void run() {
        printValues();
    }

    private synchronized void printValues() {

        for (int i = 1; i < limit; i++) {
            System.out.println(currentThread().getName() + " No = " + i);
        }

    }
}
```

Requirement: If a thread starts execution of printValues(), suppose it has to print till 10000.  Until it completes its job, no other thread should be able to enter this method.

For this I tried Lock interface as well not able to achieve this.

can anyone throw some inputs on this?

You time will be highly appreciated.

Comment: `synchronized` keyword will lock the  object for which method is called. While `printValues ` method is doing its job other thread can't access this method with same object. Other thread have to wait until `printValues` method return

Comment: I thought the same. its not happening bro. You can test the attached code.

Comment: Can you paste a log and the code calling your threads (if you still need more help)

Comment: **************** We can use semaphores. Check this. Exact Answer: https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-thread-mutex-and-semaphore-example/

Comment: Hey abdul, you only want a single execution at a time, correct? In that case a semaphore isn't what you need (a mutex (lock object) is the same as a semaphore with one permit)

Comment: Exactly, you are right. I meant semaphores with permission 1 which is a mutex. Once again I really appreciate your time spent for this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Putting synchronized means a thread has to acquire the lock (monitor) for the object instance. If you enforce only one instance of the object it stops concurrent execution.

Alternatively you can have a static lock to do the same thing

```
private static final Object lock = new Object();

public void printValues() {
    synchronized(lock) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: I really value your answer. Is there any better way?

Comment: There can be several approaches depending on what you're trying to achieve. For example if you are experiencing a specific problem maybe even Collections.synchronizedList or CopyOnWriteArrayLists can help your situation or perhaps an AtomicBoolean flag. But I would say this (my answer) is the most common approach to single access

Comment: You didn't post any more code @Abdul, so did this help you?

Comment: Not Exactly for my requirement, but it can help me.